# Can't install Melodic on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, installation, ubuntu, ubuntu-bionic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone!

I'am trying to install ROS **melodic** on **ubuntu 18.04** by the following installation guide [Installation guide](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu)

But have a problem on the **step #1.4** when I type the command:

**sudo apt install ros-melodic-desktop-full**

I am getting an error message (sorry, can't upload files yet)
kozinovsky@kozinovsky-GT70:~/Desktop$ **sudo apt install ros-melodic-desktop**
[sudo] password for kozinovsky: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
**E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-desktop**

The similar problem I saw on the forum is this:
[Similar problem](https://answers.ros.org/question/345764/e-unable-to-locate-package-ros-melodic-desktop-full-or-ros-melodic-desktop/)

Based on suggestions of this question, here is my output for
**cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list**

kozinovsky@kozinovsky-GT70:~/Desktop$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
**deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic main**

Also here is the output for **uname --all**:

kozinovsky@kozinovsky-GT70:~/Desktop$ uname --all
Linux kozinovsky-GT70 5.4.0-42-generic #46~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 07:09:27 UTC 2020 **i686 i686 i686** GNU/Linux

So, the problem itself looks like, there is no package **ros-melodic-desktop-full** available on the server, but I don't understand why, melodic is currently supported.

Another idea I have is, because I have **x32** version of ubuntu (**x686**, like I can see in the output of **uname --all**)
And on this page [melodic installation](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation)
I see in "**Select Your Platform**" for **Ubuntu Bionic** "**amd64 armhf arm64**"
Is this a problem?
Before **reinstalling the OS** I decided to ask here, what can be the issue.

Thanks everyone in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/396557/can%27t-install-melodic-on-ubuntu-18.04/) by [kozinovsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/97994/kozinovsky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2022-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Can't install Melodic on Ubuntu 18.04 [..] I have x32 version of ubuntu [..] Is this a problem?

Yes, that's the cause of the error you mention.

There are no x86 (32 bit) packages of ROS Melodic on Ubuntu Bionic (ie: `18.04`).

See also [REP 3: Target Platforms: Architectures](https://ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#architectures).

As you already found, there are only `amd64` (64 bit) packages available.

You'd have to install an `amd64` version of Bionic to be able to install Melodic using `apt`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KennyDeDavion](https://answers.ros.org/users/72611/kennydedavion/) on 2022-09-13**:
hello, and how to change so that there is no need to reinstall the image?

**Comment by [kozinovsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/97994/kozinovsky/) on 2022-09-14**:
Hi! Unfortunately, you can't change it, you need to redo the imaging with the right image (amd64 in this case)

**Comment by [KennyDeDavion](https://answers.ros.org/users/72611/kennydedavion/) on 2022-09-16**:
thank you, so if I have raspbian and ros melodic on my rpi3, is it not possible to compile with catkin without problems?